# How update state in parent component from child, child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

(sory for my english)

Hi, this code working half to half. I can delete product but i must go to another page , and back , to rerender. i dont know why ?

Code:
Parent Component:

```
function ShoppingCard() {

  const shoppingCard = useContext<any>(ShoppingCardContext);

  const [shoppingCard2, setShoppingCard2] = useState<any>(shoppingCard);

  useEffect(() => {

    setShoppingCard2(shoppingCard);

 
  }, [shoppingCard, shoppingCard2]);

  const removeProduct = (shopCart: any) => {

    let index = shoppingCard.findIndex(
      (oneProduct: any) => oneProduct.idProduct === shopCart.idProduct
    );

    shoppingCard.splice(index, 1);

    setShoppingCard2(shoppingCard);
    
  };
```

// passes this function to the next component through the next component.

```
Parent component 1
  child component 2
    child Component 3
```

And i use this fuction in a button to remove element. In console i see that shoppingCard and shoppingCard2 is update but only in child 3. And to see the efect (rerender) i must go to another page and back. In app i use React-Router.

Ps. This is my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating the state when deleting from the `shoppingCard2` array, and then never creating a ***new*** array reference for React so reconciliation works. In other words, React doesn't "see" that the `shoppingCard2` array is a ***new*** array so it doesn't trigger a rerender. You see the mutation when navigating away and back to the page.

```
const removeProduct = (shopCart: any) => {
  let index = shoppingCard.findIndex(
    (oneProduct: any) => oneProduct.idProduct === shopCart.idProduct
  );

  shoppingCard.splice(index, 1);  // <-- mutation!!

  setShoppingCard2(shoppingCard); // <-- same array reference
};
```

## Solution

Shallow copy the `shoppingCard2` array and remove the element. Use `Array.prototype.filter` to accomplish this.

Example:

```
const removeProduct = (shopCart: any) => {
  setShoppingCard2(shoppingCard => shoppingCard.filter(
    (oneProduct: any) => oneProduct.idProduct !== shopCart.idProduct
  ));
};
```

### Suggestion

An improvement would be to expose a state updater function from the `ShoppingCardContext` so it can maintain the state invariant instead of offloading this to consumers. There's really no reason to "duplicate" the shopping card state locally if it can be helped.

Answer (score -2):

The best will be to use a global state. You can read more about

- React Context
- Redux
- another state manager